# Hooks inside a controller

Tags: controller, hook, codeigniter-2

Well, I’m try to create a plugin system based on hooks, but I’m so confused in how hooks could alter a specific controller function, look the example below:

```
class Article extends CI_Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
  $title = $this->input->post('title');
  $body = $this->input->post('body');

  //try to add a new line here using hooks
  //maybe to add a new property like:
  //$published = $this->input->post('date');

  $this->my_db->save($article);

 }
}
```

How can I add a new line after the commented line? I have tried with hooks but not good results. Additionally, I thought that using hooks is the best way to create a plugin system without changing the core code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer (at least one option).You need to set "hook points" as many you need, in my case I did it by this way:

```
class Article extends CI_Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
  $title = $this->input->post('title');
  $body = $this->input->post('body');

  $article = new Article();
  $article->setTitle($title);
  $article->setBody($body);

  do_action('before_persist', $article);

  $this->my_db->save($article);

 }
}
```

Finally, my "before_persist" function have the correct code in order to add new properties to $article object

```
register_hook('before_persist', 'add_date_article', $params);
```

The add_date_article function can be declared in your custom class if you are working with CI hooks.

```
function add_date_article($params)
{
   $article = $params[0];
   $published = $this->input->post('date');
   $article->setPublished($publiched);
}
```